# Non responsive Bootstrap via lie @media queries

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have develop a complex responsive webpage layout using Bootstrap 3. The layout nicely shows the arrangement & display as expected on different screen size.

However, is it possible that I can disable the responsive for certain case use so that I set the specific layout display such as `xs`, then it will shows `xs` layout no matter what screen it is?

I am thinking could it be done by using JavaScript lying @media queries? Or, it could be easier done by using other method?

Comment: You can follow these steps: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive

Comment: @ManojKumar Thanks for your comment. But those steps are suitable for webpage build specifically for non-responsive. However, for my case here, I need to be easily turn on and off responsive on a layout originally designed for responsive.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally dependent the way you used media query and your need

Use below as per your need

```
 @media only screen and (min-width:960px){
        /* styles for browsers larger than 960px; */
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width:1440px){
        /* styles for browsers larger than 1440px; */
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width:2000px){
        /* for sumo sized (mac) screens */
    }
    @media only screen and (max-device-width:480px){
       /* styles for mobile browsers smaller than 480px; (iPhone) */
    }
    @media only screen and (device-width:768px){
       /* default iPad screens */
    }
    /* different techniques for iPad screening */
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {
      /* For portrait layouts only */
    }

    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
      /* For landscape layouts only */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in a way a interesting question.

Have a look at this Fiddle and resize the window slowly so you can see what is happening with all the Bootstrap `col-XX-XX` at the same time.

I have set up groups of cols to show you what would happen if you just used the XS class... as is for what you want to do.

When resizing the window watch how the other classes vary compared to the violet ones which are the XS cols.

You can also if needed roll your own **[here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints)** and set your own breakpoints.

Full size **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vz0ogtj7/embedded/result/)** here.